# Visual Studio + nuget + TFS: checking in nuget packages?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I'm working on a TFS project with a small team.  This project has a bunch of nuget packages installed, but it's for a 4.0 project, and the nuget package manager GUI doesn't even offer the older versions of the packages any longer since their 4.5 equivalents are now being used.  In order to allow other team members to compile the project, they need to have the exact versions of the packages.  I'd like to check in the entire "packages" folder used by nuget.  Is this a good idea?  If so, how does one check in the "packages" folder and all its contents since it exists at the solution level?  There is no "Include in Solution" option in Visual Studio as there is when you right-click an assembly.

Comment: The nuget package manager should download the old package as long as it is present on the server. As far as I know you're not allowed to delete a package from the nuget server if it has at least 1 download.

Answer (score 1):

in the past I have also checked in the NuGet packages into version control. With this some problems appeared:

1. Some packages where not checked into version control when committing from Visual Studio into TFS.
2. Updating packages became a real problem.

For the first problem I had used the [TFS Power Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/09/22/tfs-2013-power-tools-are-available.aspx). The problem with this solution is that every developer needed to install the Power Tools.

A better solution came up with NuGet 2.7. It introduced [package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages). With package restore there's no need to check-in the packages folder. They will be restored during build.

Answer (score 1):

We use an on-prem TFS install with no internet access so we have to check in our package folders or our builds fail. The biggest issue is that VS does not behave consistently when it comes to adding the pending changes for new package files, often times it will ignore the .dll files in the pending changes window, sometimes it adds everything fine.